# User is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, api-gateway

I'm trying to call an api-gateway endpoint from my web app but getting the error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::<number>:assumed-role/my_identity_pool_auth_role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:********9277:<api-gateway id>/test/GET/theme
```

I have a user pool set up in which I've created two groups, one of which I'd like to give access to execute the endpoint mentioned above.

The user pool group has an iam role attached with no permissions, but the following trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<identity pool id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and a tag with:

```
key: user_role
value: end_user_basic
```

The identity pool auth role has permissions and trust relationship below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:*:<api-gateway id>/*/GET/theme",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/user_role": "end_user_basic"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<identity pool id>"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the identity pool settings, I have 'authenticated role selection' set to 'user default role' and 'attributes for access control' set to 'use custom mappings' with the below:

```
Tag key for principal: user_role
Attribute name: user_role
```

And when I make the request, my id token has a payload something like below:

```
{
  "sub": ...,
  "cognito:groups": [
    "<the correct cognito user group>"
  ],
  "iss": ...,
  "cognito:username": ...,
  "origin_jti": ...,
  "cognito:roles": [
    "<the correct iam role with tag attached>"
  ],
  "aud": ...,
  "event_id": ...,
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "iat": ...,
  "jti": ...,
  "email": ...
}
```

so the user belongs to the correct group with the correct iam role applied.

I'm new to AWS so I'm sure i'm missing something daft but if somebody could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

As an aside, if I remove the condition below:

```
"Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/user_role": "end_user_basic"
                }
            }
```

from the identity pool auth role, I can make the api call successfully